# Logging profiles for different environments (Java)

Tags: java, logging

Is there anything in the prod-ready logging world like env-dependent logging profiles. What I mean. Usually one wants different level of detail for different environments.

In action it requires creating multiple log configuration files and when having many environments adding new logger becomes real pain. What I am looking for is:

```
<logger name="com.google.xyz" additivity="true">
        <level value="DEBUG" env="DEV" />
        <level value="INFO" env="UAT" />
        <level value="ERROR" env="PROD" />
        <appender-ref ref="xyz-appender"/>
    </logger>
```

Is such thing exists for some prod-ready Java logging solution?

Answer (score 1):

Logback (an excellent choice for logging with SLF4J) seems to offer this capability in a verbose, but very configurable form.

[Conditional processing of configuration files](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#conditional)

Comment: Given the other features it provides... Really cool framework.